# I want to use Ledger Nano S to deploy the contract, but not working

Tags: contract-deployment, truffle-migration, ledger-nano-s

I wanted to deploy the contract with the Ledger Nano S wallet, but not working on truffle. I installed npm package 'truffle-ledger-provider' and followed the practice. But I got an error `ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined` when I tried to deploy. I've searched google, but there was no good solution. Please help me.

Comment: What OS you have?

Comment: I use MacOS @ferit

Comment: If the reason for using a Ledger for deploying the contract is security, you don't have to use a hardware wallet necessarily. See this: [Best security practices for contract deployment?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/109553/best-security-practices-for-contract-deployment/109554#109554).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the fix. I just ran into this issue today.

```
// truffle-config.js
const regeneratorRuntime = require("regenerator-runtime");
```

Then install the NPM package:
`npm install regenerator-runtime`