# Best security practices for contract deployment?

Tags: solidity, remix, metamask, truffle-deployment

I'm using Truffle to develop an ERC721 smart contract.

Truffle expects [HDWalletProvider](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@truffle/hdwallet-provider) to be installed so that Truffle can sign transactions for you, however this requires storing your mnemonic locally and importing it into Truffle's config file. Isn't that really insecure? I've seen approaches where it's kept in a .env file, however this still seems vulnerable.

What's considered best practice from a security P.O.V?

Would it be deploying via Remix and MetaMask, with MetaMask connected to a hardware wallet so that the wallet's mnemonic and private key are never stored?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Best Approach

Deploy with any method you want (even a MNEMONIC stored in a `.env` file) then immediately transfer the ownership of the contracts to a [Gnosis Safe](https://gnosis-safe.io/) multisig controlled by multiple signers. If you're using OpenZeppelin's [Ownable.sol](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol), you do this via [transferOwnership](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/aefcb3e8aa4ee8da8e2b7022ffe4dcb57fbb0fdf/contracts/access/Ownable.sol#L61-L64).

### 2nd Best Approach

Use a hardware wallet like Ledger or Trezor, load your contracts in [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org) and deploy with [MetaMask](https://metamask.io).

Pro tip: [connect to localhost](https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/remixd.html) so you don't have to copy-paste the contracts' source code.

Comment: Thanks Paul, can Gnosis safe be used to sign transactions that are initiated elsewhere (e.g. from a truffle script: https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/truffle-commands#exec)? Or do I have to use the contract interaction interface within gnosis?

Comment: There is a way to sign transactions created programatically. Check out OpenZeppelin's [Gnosis Safe plugin](https://blog.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-app-for-gnosis-safe/) and the [step-by-step tutorial for Hardhat](https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/openzeppelin-upgrades-step-by-step-tutorial-for-hardhat/3580). Truffle doesn't seem to be supported though.

Comment: If you have the bandwidth to do this, I highly recommend you migrate to [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/). It's just 10x better and faster than Truffle.

Comment: Good call - Hardhat seems pretty powerful!

Comment: Nice! Now a shameless plug: check out my [solidity-template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template), which combines Hardhat and other goodies.

Comment: Funnily enough I was trying this the other week, really helpful! Do you have an example of running hardhat scripts that propose transactions to gnosis (for other owners to sign in the UI)? I'm switching the owner to the safe as you suggested above, but finding it hard to get the gnosis safe sdk working from a hardhat script.

Comment: Actually, got it working! Nonetheless if you've got some examples I'd love to see them to check if I'm doing everything correctly.

Comment: I don't have any scripts for that, unfortunately.