# Using Gnosis Safe to deploy a smart contract

Tags: gnosis-safe

I have created a contract on goerli that allows people to create and sell NFTs. The contract takes a commission on all sales, and these commissions accumulate in the account of the contract "owner". Currently the contract owner is set as the address that is used to deploy the contract. Only the contract owner is allowed to withdraw the accumulated commissions.

I am working on a small team, and would like for this withdrawal process to require approval from more than one member of the team. I suspect this is possible using Gnosis Safe, however after reviewing the documentation, I'm not sure.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to deploy a contract from a Gnosis Safe account?
2. If not, is it possible to use the "Safe App SDK" to accomplish this?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at ape-safe: https://github.com/banteg/ape-safe

Comment: Why bother deploying from the Gnosis Safe when you [could change the owner later](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/109553/best-security-practices-for-contract-deployment/109554#109554)?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg Thank you. What if I take it one step further and just hard code the gnosis safe address into the contract? Maybe this is a separate question related to best practices.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CreateCall library to deploy Contracts:
https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/libraries/CreateCall.sol