# Using GnosisSafe to deploy ERC20

Tags: blockchain, ether, gnosis-safe

We want to use GnosisSafe to deploy a ERC-20 (Ethereum blockchain).

1. deploy ERC-20 and
2. immediately mint tokens to the safe account.

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks

Comment: you can change the constructor on your ERC20 and include `_mint(GnosisSafeWalletAddress, amount)`

Answer (score 3):

You could change the owner after deploying, but if you want to do it with the Safe itself: You can use the CreateCall library to deploy Contracts: https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/libraries/CreateCall.sol

Referencing [Using Gnosis Safe to deploy a smart contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/117909/using-gnosis-safe-to-deploy-a-smart-contract)