# How do I deploy a smart contract from a gnosis safe address

Tags: contract-deployment, gnosis-safe

I want to deploy a contract using a gnosis safe address so the gnosis safe is the owner. I'm using this script https://github.com/greenlucid/yubiai-contracts/blob/main/howto.md. But its asking for the private key of the owner(Gnosis safe) and in the Docs of Safe it says that the signer of the Safe is from which I should get the private key, https://help.safe.global/en/articles/5333988-export-signer-key, however when pass the private key of the wallet signer(because I don't see where i can get the safe private key) and execute the deploy, in gnosis scan I see that the owner of the contract is the signer and not the safe. Btw the contract doesn't have a changeGovernor function, so we can't transfer ownership from the singer to the safe, if we add this the deploy would be delayed because will need to pass trough more audits and testing. Is there a way to have some sort of private key from the safe address ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/117909/using-gnosis-safe-to-deploy-a-smart-contract

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Gnosis Safe to deploy a smart contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/117909/using-gnosis-safe-to-deploy-a-smart-contract)

Comment: Hye thanks for answering, no it doesnt but we just solved with a transfer from fn